# Difference between Inflection and Declension

Tags: word-usage

I had looked up the dictionary regarding the meaning of Declension and it denotes : a list of Inflections.

What is the main difference between inflection and Declension? To What does the dictionary refer with the word list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It helps if you think about it this way: when learning about language grammar, verbs are conjugated and nouns (for example) are declined.

The changes that must be made to a noun to decline it (the act of "declension") are called "inflections."

Thus, when you decline the word "dog" to make it plural, the word is inflected by adding an "s" on the end to create "dogs."

Read [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) for a detailed discussion about inflection.

Read [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension) for a detailed discussion about declension.

---

The basic definition of "decline" is "to reduce."  In English grammar, a noun (etc.) is declined (reduced) from its general form to a specific form.

What you actually do to change the word is "inflection."

Comment: Decline means reducd a height or vertical measure. What do you refer to with verb decline im this context?

Comment: Visit [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decline), scroll down to the "transitive verb" section and read definition #1.  "Decline" is the root form of "Declension."

Comment: It looks to me decline inflect are all changing forms of word for encapsulating the information about case, number and sometimes gender.

Comment: They are different.  Very simply, "decline" describes why the words must change.  "Inflect" describes how the words are changed.

Comment: You smart one.. impressed by your depth of brevity